# How to create an async function in a nodejs server that works in parallel with client connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, client-server

I'm trying to make a simulation in nodeJS of a thread in a client server-application that modifies datas at an interval of 20ms and a listener and a sender. The lisener needs to check datas from server every 1s and the sender send some informations to the server when needed.

I've tried to create the server and the a setInterval that connects a client to read datas, but it seems that every time i'm connecting the client all datas in server resets and my run function is not working properly.

```
function sleep(time) {
    return function (callback) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(time);
            callback();
        }, time);
    }
}


var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    var i = 1;

    var totalTime = 1000;
    var time = 20;
    while (time<totalTime){
        run(function*(){
            i++;
            yield sleep(20);
            console.log("modified datas!"+ i);
        });
        time +=20;
    }




    socket.write('write to client\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');


setInterval(
    function () {
        var net = require('net');

        var client = "1";
        var i = 0;
        var client = new net.Socket();

        client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function () {
            console.log('Connected');

            // client.write("Send from client");
        });



        client.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log('DATAS IN CLIENT:::: ' + data);
            i++;
            if (i == 2)
                client.destroy();
            // client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
        });

        client.on('close', function () {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        });

    },
    6000
);
```

Here is my terminal from now.

```
Connected
DATAS IN CLIENT:::: write to client

20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
...

Connected
DATAS IN CLIENT:::: write to client

20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
20
modified datas!50
```

and I'm looking for datas to be continued when I'm connecting a new client

```
Connected
DATAS IN CLIENT:::: write to client

20
modified datas!1
20
modified datas!2
20
modified datas!3
20
modified datas!5
20
modified datas!6
...

Connected
DATAS IN CLIENT:::: write to client

20
modified datas!7
20
modified datas!8
20
modified datas!9
20
modified datas!10
20
modified datas!11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run() function code is not posted so it is difficult to understand what parts of your code is actually doing.

But from the code you have posted the variable `i` in the server is being set to 1 on each connection and subsequently being modified in your while/run loop.

If you want to preserve the value of `i` between socket connections you will have to define it outside of the `net.createServer` callback ( in the global scope ).

Comment: I moved the var i =0 declaration outside and it's working now, It's the correct way to have a setInterval function that creates clients to see what the servers does or there is a way to create a permanent listener to server?

Comment: It looks like websockets would be the better approach in your case.  This has more abstraction and functionality built in.  look at the `ws` module on npm which interfaces with `WebSockets` built into most browsers.  Alternatively you could use socket.io which has both backend and client side libraries.